# How to make enumeration xsd make forward compatible in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

As we can use any and anyattribute tag to make schema forward/backward compatible. is there any was to do same for enumeration ? I am using JAXB for marshalling and marshalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

- Keep "old" enum entries forever.
- Don't compile to enums.
- Specify your own enum (and keep "old" enum entries there forever).

Comment: thanks for the answer but is there no way like JAXB provide for tag (<any>) ?

Comment: @user1047873 If you model this as an enum, think about how this "unsupported" value will be represented in Java. If there's no enum for this value, there's nothing you can assign to the property, period. Well, maybe you could use your oft enum-like class and a custom type converter, but that would be the same as to drop enums.